# SSRS pass an array of parameters

Tags: parameters, ssrs-2008

I have a report I built for baseball player stats.  We want to provide the option to pass either 1 playerID to SSRS to generate 1 report or to pass a variable number of playerIDs and generate a report for each.

Whats giving me the issue is that this needs to be in one report window.  So I pass 3 playerIDs, I get back one report with 3 pages - each page showing a different player.

How do I go about this?  I've tried subreports and have gotten multiple pages to generate, but every page comes out with the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable number of IDs, but I am not so sure that you can cater for a variable number of parameters.

To access your paramater value it is:

Parameters!PlayerIDs.Value(0),Parameters!PlayerIDs.Value(1), Parameters!PlayerIDs.Value(2) etc